# Importing library project multiple times in Android Studio 1.3.1 causes library to disappear

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have a library project called Common that I use for functionality that is shared by my other projects, Consumer and Management. Consumer itself is also a library project that is used by other apps.

The build.gradle file in Common contains all external dependencies used by the other projects like so:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
```

This downloads the following libraries:

[image]

This list remains unchanged when I add Common to either Consumer, Management or both. When I add the Consumer to MyApp like so:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':consumer')
}
```

This happens:

[image]

The support library just disappears, wreaking complete havoc in my project. This did not happen before updating to Android Studio 1.3.1 so I'm really wondering what the problem might be.

For reference these are the complete gradle.build files:

**Common**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
```

**Management**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "eu.test.mgmt"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 22
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':common')
}
```

**Consumer**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 18
        versionName "1.3"
        multiDexEnabled = true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/xml', 'src/main/res/xml'] } }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':common')
}
```

**MyApp:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "eu.test.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 19
        versionName "1.4"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':consumer')
}
```

Comment: Only odd thing I can see is that you specify repositories in the Consumer `build.gradle`. Perhaps try removing that block as it doesn't seem necessary, although I'm also not sure that would be causing your issue.

Comment: two questions!! have you tried adding :common as direct dependency ? then also appCompat library is not shown?   and adding :management as dependency also causes same problems?

Comment: does it missing in IDE only?
try to
`./gradlew your_app:dependencies`

and provide output

Answer (score 0):

Try to click the icon of the project structure and check the details about the structure. Sometimes it just may be you import the library missing some important steps

Answer (score 0):

It is good to **clean** and **rebuild** project after importing or removing any library, so that there will not be any ***GC*** in Android Studio.

Comment: I think this issues were in old Android studio. By using latest version 4.2.1 we will not get these types of errors.